# Url.Kentico().Attachment() method to retrieve page attachment URLs in MVC application

Tags: kentico

I'm trying to create a simple Kentico MVC Application.
In Kentico application, I've created a content structure like this [Site content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmO3G.png)

I've also followed [Working with page attchments in MVC application](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Working+with+page+attachments+in+MVC+applications) to read the articles and show teaser images but not working. The API returns a string like `http://localhost/kmvc/getattachment/ddf88493-ac48-472a-97a7-8c25a889d29e/instagramcapture_eda60074-60c4-4b75-b2d9-25072549f9bc_jpg.jpg`

Here is site information:

```
Site domain name: localhost
Presentation URL: http://localhost/kmvc
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have followed the [initial setup steps](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Starting+with+MVC+development#StartingwithMVCdevelopment-SettinguptheMVCapplication) thoroughly, especially the sixth step - route configuration. Example [here](https://github.com/Kentico/Mvc/blob/master/src/DancingGoat/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs#L20)...

Also, make sure that routes in your application don't collide with the routes reserved by Kentico which, in case of attachments, are:

```c#
[assembly: RegisterHttpHandler("CMSPages/GetFile.aspx", typeof(GetAttachmentHandler), Order = 1)]
[assembly: RegisterHttpHandler("getfile/{nodeguid:guid}/{filename}", typeof(GetAttachmentHandler), Order = 2)]
[assembly: RegisterHttpHandler("cms/getfile/{nodeguid:guid}/{filename}", typeof(GetAttachmentHandler), Order = 3)]
[assembly: RegisterHttpHandler("getimage/{guid:guid}/{filename}", typeof(GetAttachmentHandler), Order = 4)]
[assembly: RegisterHttpHandler("getattachment/{guid:guid}/{filename}", typeof(GetAttachmentHandler), Order = 5)]
[assembly: RegisterHttpHandler("cms/getattachment/{guid:guid}/{filename}", typeof(GetAttachmentHandler), Order = 6)]
[assembly: RegisterHttpHandler("getattachment/{*pathandfilename}", typeof(GetAttachmentHandler), Order = 7)]
[assembly: RegisterHttpHandler("cms/getattachment/{*pathandfilename}", typeof(GetAttachmentHandler), Order = 8)]
```

If you are still unable to resolve the problem, add more details about the error you are getting and perhaps code of your RouteConfig.cs (and other relevant code files).

Comment: Thanks Rocky. I've resolved the problem. It is to register Kentico routes first.

Comment: No problem. Did my answer help you solve the problem? If so, please consider marking it as a correct answer. Thx